# Factorial with recursion in C: why my code is running?

Tags: c, recursion

Normally, I must use "else return 1". However, it works without that line. Thanks for answers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int f(int x)
    {
          if(x!=1)
          return x*f(x-1);

          //else return 1

    }
    int main()
    {
      int x;scanf("%d",&x);
        printf("%d",f(x));
    }
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior, it's just "working" by accident.

Comment: Why do you think it's working? `f(1)` should be `1`, not `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's undefined behavior. The return value holds no meaning as far as the factorial is concerned. In fact factorial of `1` is `1` not `3` so it is giving an incorrect result. There is no meaning whatsoever.  Even if it gave you correct result - on this case `1` don't think that this is somehow a correct code and will work no matter what. It won't.

Also the compiler mentioned about this when you complied with all flags enabled. `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`.

To explain undefined behavior:-

The standard explicitly chooses to not define how a compiler
should behave if it encounters Undefined Behavior. As a result, a compiler is free to do whatever it sees fit and may produce useful results, unexpected results, or even crash. You shouldn't rely on that.